# Connection reset while uploading large file ? Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have a function that need to allow users upload files. I was able to upload small files to server without any issues. But when it comes to large file, I am getting this.

```
Chrome: FAILED to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.
```

After I went through some searching, I found that I need to change the maximum file size in web.config. Then, another problem arise where the upload percentage keep starting from 0% again after uploading about 60%. It keep on doing this 2 to 3 times then it gives the the same Chrome error. I was able to upload large files from localhost and unable to do it when I put my web in server. The file size is about 110 MB.

This is my web config.

1. In system.web

   ```
   <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true" maxRequestLength="2000000000" maxQueryStringLength="1024" executionTimeout="999999" requestLengthDiskThreshold="15360" />
   ```
2. In system.webServer

   ```
   <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295"></requestLimits>
   ```

Comment: Any limits set by the host?

Comment: Up. Some progress?